# having an error : "missing 1 required positional argument", even though i am entering the argument

Tags: python, typeerror

```
class sum:
    def fx(self, op, a, b, c, d):
        if(op == 1):
            self.output = self.addition(a, b, c, d)
        else:
            self.output = self.subtraction(a, b, c, d)

    def addition(self, a, b, c, d):
        return a+b+c+d

    def subtraction(self, a, b, c, d):
        return a-b-c-d

x = sum.fx(1, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

The above code gives an error

> x = sum.fx(1, 1, 2, 3, 4)
> TypeError: sum.fx() missing 1 required positional argument: 'd'

I am clearly entering the value parameter 'd' but it says that i am not. It should give an output "10"

Comment: `sum` is the name of the class. You didn't create an instance of it, so calling a member method like that won't work this way. One way to make this work is `sum().fx(1, 1, 2, 3, 4)`

Comment: `sum` is a class.  You're supposed to declare an _instance_ of the class, like this `mysum = sum()` and then call the method on the instance `mysum.fx(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `sum().fx(...)`. The first argument you passed is considered to be the instance of the class (`self`) but if we consider that then you are missing one of the arguments `d` that you need to pass?

You should instantiate in this case first to call the methods.

Note: By using the `self` we can access the attributes and methods of the class in python. In your case, even if you provide extra random arguments `.fx(1,1,2,3,4)` it would run into error later. Because you don't have the instance of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you want the sum class to be like a Library of mathematical functions you could declare the methods as @classmethods:

```
class Sum:
    @classmethod
    def fx(cls, op, a, b, c, d):
        if op == 1:
            output = cls.addition(a, b, c, d)
        else:
            output = cls.subtraction(a, b, c, d)
        return output

    @classmethod
    def addition(cls, a, b, c, d):
        return a+b+c+d

    @classmethod
    def subtraction(cls, a, b, c, d):
        return a-b-c-d

x = Sum.fx(1, 1, 2, 3, 4)
print(x)
```

This way you do not need to create a class instance, just use the functions